# Rails - devise and sidekiq routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq-monitor

I am running a Rails 5.0.0 app with Ruby 2.3.1

Sidekiq is being used for background jobs and devise for authentication.

Sidekiq monitoring and devise are mounted in routes as follows:

```
devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions]
    as :user do
        get    'login' => 'devise/sessions#new',      :as => :new_user_session
        post   'login' => 'devise/sessions#create',   :as => :user_session
        delete 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
    end

require 'sidekiq/web'
    require 'sidekiq/cron/web'
    #Sidekiq::Web.set :session_secret, Rails.application.secrets[:secret_key_base]
    authenticate :user do
        mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
    end
```

But, accessing the sidekiq status page logs out the user.

The same code used to work fine with Rails 4.2.5

Comment: I would search through these gems github repositories. Rails 5.0 and ruby 2.3 are very recent, they may not be fully compatible with the gems.

Comment: If an urgent fix is needed you can remove devise and roll your own auth with bcrypt since that seems to be working fine for 5.0.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try wrapping your mounting of Sidekiq under `devise_scope`, in the same way you're using its alias "`as`" in your `devise_for` route:

```
# Only allow authenticated users to get access
# to the Sidekiq web interface
devise_scope :user do
  authenticated :user do
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a snippet for that allows for custom authentication on the Sidekiq routes.

```
authenticate :user, ->(user) { user.admin? || Other auth related checks... } do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => "/sidekiq"
end
```

Comment: Any documentation or examples on how to test this in rspec?

Comment: For those seeking such, here are the official docs around this route authentication support:
- https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Define-resource-actions-that-require-authentication-using-routes.rb
- https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/ec0674523e7909579a5a008f16fb9fe0c3a71712/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L274-L294