# Sidekiq's web interface logs out the user in Rails 5.2.3

Tags: sidekiq

I finally narrowed this issue down to the Sidekiq web interface. Whenever I'm using my app, everything works perfectly fine -- I can open new tabs and everything without an interrupted session.

However, the minute I browse to my app's sidekiq interface, it logs me out of my authenticated session.

Here's what I have in my `config/routes` file:

```
  require "sidekiq/pro/web"
  devise_scope :user do
    root to: "devise/sessions#new"

    authenticated :user do
      mount Sidekiq::Web => "/sidekiq", constraints: lambda { |request| request.remote_ip == "MY_IP_ADDERSS" }
    end
  end
```

This answer was suggested by [Rails - devise and sidekiq routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742116/rails-devise-and-sidekiq-routes). However, I have tried implementing that, as shown above, and it still doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong in this scenario?

Here's my `config/initializers/session_store.rb` if this helps:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store, key: "session_key_#{Rails.env}"
```

Answer (score 0):

[this post](https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/issues/3377#issuecomment-381254940) helped me with the same problem. Looks like Sidekiq UI does not like the overwrites that `activerecord-session_store` promotes on the application. [Here](https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/issues/4671#issuecomment-770279766) you can find a longer discussion about this topic with some suggestions to work around this problem.